# Convert 3 columns of data on one sheet to a single row

Tags: excel

I have 100 contacts in 3 columns in SHEET 1,

> A1 = FIRST NAME,
>   B1 = LAST NAME and
>   C1 = Ph No.

I want to be able to drag out a single row on another sheet (SHEET 2) which references these three columns and drops a row every three columns.

```
'SHEET2'!A1 = 'SHEET1'!A1
'SHEET2'!B1 = 'SHEET1'!B1
'SHEET2'!C1 = 'SHEET1'!C1
'SHEET2'!D1 = 'SHEET1'!A2
'SHEET2'!E1 = 'SHEET1'!B2
'SHEET2'!F1 = 'SHEET1'!C2
'SHEET2'!G1 = 'SHEET1'!A3
'SHEET2'!H1 = 'SHEET1'!B3
'SHEET2'!I1 = 'SHEET1'!C3
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I marked down your column description by separating it and using a leading >.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this Formula in `Sheet2!A1` and drag across

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$C,INT((COLUMN()-1)/3)+1,MOD(COLUMN()-1,3)+1)
```

Or as a UDF

```
Function TransposeBy3(Src As Range) As Variant
    Dim rw As Long, cl As Long
    rw = (Application.ThisCell.Column - 1) \ 3 + 1
    cl = (Application.ThisCell.Column - 1) Mod 3 + 1
    TransposeBy3 = Src.Cells(rw, cl).Value
End Function
```

Place Forumula `=TransposeBy3(Sheet1!$A:$C)` in `Sheet2!A1` and drag across

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much Chris! :-)